# How to get specific data from excel

Tags: python-3.x

[image: Binnings]

Any idea on how can I acccess or get the box data (see image) under TI_Binning tab of excel file using python? What module or similar code you can recommend to me? I just need those specifica data and append it on other file such as .txt file.

Answer (score 1):

Getting the data you circled:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('yourfilepath', 'TI_Binning', skiprows=2)
df = df[['Number', 'Name']]
```

To appending to an existing text file:

```
import numpy as np
with open("filetoappenddata.txt", "ab") as f:
    np.savetxt(f, df.values)
```

More info here on [np.savetxt](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) for formats to fit your output need.

Comment: Hey bro Brian! thank you very much! I got the result as expected :)

Comment: Hello Brian, one more thing, just notice that I didn't got the desired data extraction. I am getting the data under "Class" column. Can you help me how can I tweak the program to get the data under "Category" column? that's what I wanted, thank you!

Comment: I didn't notice that, you have multiple columns with the same name. You should grab these by their index value so as I count this from left to right:

`df.iloc[:, [6, 7]]` since python has 0 based indexes

Comment: Nice! I finally got it this time ,thank you again! have a nice day :)